# i need to verify the same label name which exists in different pages

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<span class="ui-column-title">Contractor Name</span>
.//*[@id='commonAppContainer']/div/section[2]/div/div/billing-queue-list/div/section[2]/div/p-datatable/div/div/table/thead/tr/th[1]/span[1]

<span class="ui-column-title">Contractor Name</span>
.//*[@id='active']/section/div/p-datatable/div/div/table/thead/tr/th[2]/span[1]
```

I need to verify the same label name which exists in different pages .

How to write common object for the below in POM frame work.

Comment: You should always add a tag for the language that you are using, e.g. add the Java tag to this question.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `XPath` which will match your element on all pages (if not, you should provide extended `HTML` to get more specific `XPath`)

```
//span[@class="ui-column-title"]
```

P.S. Getting text value of element depends on programming language you use. For example, on `Python` code should looks like

```
assert driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="ui-column-title"]').text == "Contractor Name"
```

Comment: thanks for your update i am using java and how to use an a object i am declaring as a common  object and will use in the various class